# How to create bash script that combines specified list of items at random?

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have 2 list of items

```
Honda
Toyota
Ford
BMW
```

&

```
Red
Blue
White
Black
Silver
Yellow
```

And I was to write a bash script that combines this list with randomized configurations. How would I do that?

Example output:

```
Honda Black
BMW Yellow
Ford White
Toyota Red
```

Comment: it's just [`shuf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shuf.1.html) + [`paste`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your comment below the answer indicates you wish to store the shuffled lists within the script itself rather than relying on an external utility. While you could just call the utilities within your script, you can also "house the list of items" within the script using arrays in bash. (while it is unclear whether you mean the final list or the initial lists, your use of the plural form suggests the initial lists).

To store the list from the file in arrays in your script in shuffled order, you can simply use a command substitution, e.g.

```
brands=( $(shuf brands.txt) )   ## fill brands array with shuffled brands.txt
colors=( $(shuf colors.txt ) )  ## fill colors array with shuffled colors.txt
```

(if you want the original unshuffled lists, simply replace `shuf` with `<`)

(**note:** if any line can include whitespace, you will want to set the *Internal Field Separator* variable (`IFS`) to only break on newlines before filling your arrays, or as an alternative use `mapfile -t` to fill them)

Then to select an element from `brands` and from `colors` to put them together, simply use a C-style `for` loop to put like indexes together, e.g.

```
for ((i = 0; i < limit; i++)); do
    printf "%s %s\n" "${brands[i]}" "${colors[i]}"
done
```

(where `limit` above is just the lesser number of elements between `brands` and `colors`)

Putting the entire script together and setting `IFS` as described above, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

oifs="$IFS"     ## save original IFS (Internal Field Separator)
IFS=$'\n'       ## set IFS to only break on newlines (if spaces in lines)

brands=( $(shuf brands.txt) )   ## fill brands array with shuffled brands.txt
colors=( $(shuf colors.txt ) )  ## fill colors array with shuffled colors.txt

IFS="$oifs"     ## restore original IFS

limit=${#brands[@]}     ## find array with least no. of elements
[ "${#colors[@]}" -lt "$limit" ] && limit=${#colors[@]}

for ((i = 0; i < limit; i++)); do
    printf "%s %s\n" "${brands[i]}" "${colors[i]}"
done
```

Which when running will produce your random mappings, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash shuffled.sh
BMW White
Ford Yellow
Honda Black
Toyota Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows. Create a shuffeled version of colors and brands and then combine them.

```
#!/bin/bash

shuf brands.txt > brands_shuffeled.txt
shuf colors.txt > colors_shuffeled.txt
paste -d " " brands_shuffeled.txt colors_shuffeled.txt | grep -v -e "^ " -e ' $'
```

The grep command just removes the lines for which you only have a color or a brand, but not both parts (with your data, we will only have lines which only contain a color, since there are more colors than brands).

The output looks like:

```
Toyota Red
Honda Yellow
Ford Blue
BMW White
```

Comment: I see. Is there a way to house the lists of items within the script itself rather than calling it externally?

Comment: An array, e.g. `brands=( $(shuf brands.txt) )` and `colors=( $(shuf colors.txt ) )`. Of course if you are storing them, you still have to put the combinations together which you could do with a C-style `for` loop.